# Jquery iterate with each on sub object

Tags: jquery, json, loops, each

```
I have this JSON:

    {  
       "letter":[  
          {  
             "offerHeader":"Tilbud fra myCompany AS",
             "offerComment":"Mitt lille tilbud kommer inn her",
             "offerComment1":"NB.  Vi gjør opmerksom på at våre bokser inneholder mye mer enn konkurrentenes",
         "offerComment2":"Tilbudet gjelder i 100 dager. Alle priser er uten. mva, frakt og annet vi måtte komme på.",
         "offerComment3":"Ved eventuelle spørsmål kontaktes selger på tlf. 99999999.",
         "offerRegards":"Vennlig hilsen",
         "offerRepUs":"myCompany AS",
         "offerRepPhone":"Telefon: +47 99999999",
         "offerRepEmail":"Epost: noreply@myCompany.no",
         "offerRepWeb":"Internettet: www.myCopmany.no"
      }
   ],
        "prods":[  
          {  
             "a":"02.1435",
             "b":"Coating sort",
             "c":"10§",
             "d":"599.00",
             "e":"539.10"
          },
          {  
             "a":"07.1600",
             "b":"Electro Seal",
             "c":"25§",
             "d":"159.00",
             "e":"119.25"
          }
       ],
       "prodLines":"2",
       "offerTxt":[  
          {  
             "offerCompany":"kalles Jensebøff",
             "offerContact":"jensen",
             "offerAddress":"gata",
             "offerAddress2":"oppgang 4",
             "offerPost":"1200 stedtnavn"
      }
   ]
}

$.each(revText.letter, function(index, value) {
    $('#offerHeader').html(value['offerHeader']);
    $('#offerComment').html(value['offerComment']);
});
```

I can use $.each to fetch data from the first part of the JSON under the flag "letter". Problem is, I want to run an $.each (or iteration) on the part "prods". I have tried to nest $.each without success.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I go about reading the "prods" part of the JSON ?

I have tried:

---

```
 $.each(value.prods, function(i,v) {
   ....
 })

 $.each(value['prods'], function(i,v) {
   ....
 });

 $.each(revText.letter, function(ii, vv) {
   $.each(vv.prods, function(i,v) {
    ....
   });
 });
```

and another number of things which I don't even recall at the moment.
Any pointers at all will be very gratefully received.

Comment: **...** `revText.prods`? `prods` is on the same level as `letter`, so iterating over it would be pretty similar.

Comment: thank you. sometimes the correct answer is there, under your nose. blush.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Kevin B for actually pointing out the obvious. 
I swear I dod try that as well. must've been a hickup somewhere.

But yes, in my case they are on the same level. So no need to treat it as a sub-level..

Solution:

```
 $.each(revText.prods, function(i,v) {
  .....
 });
```